# How do I launch Ubuntu 16.04 LTS from the terminal?

Tags: command-line, 16.04, upgrade

I have just upgraded to 16.04 LTS but I now just get a terminal screen with the following message :

> Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.2.0-42-generic x86_64)
>   Documentation: https...
>   Management: https...
>   Support: https...
>
> To run a command as administrator (user "root"), use "sudo "
>   See "man sudo_root" for details."

But I don't know which command is needed to launch ubuntu from this point.

Can anybody help ?

Comment: Did you install the server or desktop version? The command to start the x server is `startx` but you should not need to do that as Ubuntu desktop has a display manager by default.

Comment: I think your upgrade failed and stuck at some point. Did you try switching to vt7 b y `Ctrl-Alt-F7`?

Comment: Thanks Zanna. I'm pretty sure I installed the desktop version. Should I try to startx command anyway?

Comment: @Anwar Thanks. No, I didn't. Should I try that now?

Comment: Yes. You should try it

Comment: @Anwar by the way, what is vt7 ?

Comment: You can try `startx` but try Anwar's suggestion first. Something needs fixing though if you have to do these things. vt7 = virtual terminal 7 which is where you should find the x server running

Comment: @Zanna  blimey, something really is wrong. After doing Ctl-Alt-F7 I just get this in the top of the terminal: 9^[[20~

Comment: Install a display manager `sudo apt install lightdm` and restart using `sudo reboot`.

Comment: @Anwar success ! The command sudo apt install lightdm followed by sudo reboot worked perfectly. You're a legend, thanks. Mons

Comment: @Mons I'm writing an answer converting the comments

Comment: @Anwar OK, great. The problem may have originated in an interruption in the (slow) network connection during the upgrade. Thanks again.

Comment: @Mons You can upvote or accept answer if that works :) these works as "Thanks".  http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 1):

I think somehow your upgrade went wrong. Try switching to Virtual Termnal 7 by `Ctrl-Alt-F7` and there you'll see the login screen.

If you can't see that login screen, use `startx` (after going back to VT1 pressing `Ctrl-Alt-F1`) to start the graphical session. If the graphical session starts, install a display manager which should handle the login prompts automatically after each reboot now.

```
sudo apt install lightdm
```

If that too doesn't work, install `lightdm` from the VT1 (where you originally were) using the above command `sudo apt-get install lightdm` and reboot with `sudo reboot`.

It should solve the problem.